# Move jQuery to the bottom of the page whilst keeping the WordPress jQuery

Tags: jquery, wp-enqueue-script, wp-register-script

I wish to move jQuery to the bottom of the page on my theme, to speed up loading times.

Previously I was doing this by replacing it with Google's CDN version but I have been told that is a bad thing to do.

How can I deregister and re-register the WordPress jQuery script and move it to the bottom without causing any problems?

Comment: Why? Using Google’s jQuery will break many plugins, because it works differently.

Comment: Here is a post why loading jQuery from a CDN isn't a ´good´ idea.
http://pippinsplugins.com/why-loading-your-own-jquery-is-irresponsible/

Comment: OK I did not know about the problems with using Google's CDN. I will instead just move it to the footer. Thanks.

Comment: This definitely has causing issue. I've received some complaints about this. It turns out optimize press theme is doing this......

Comment: OK guys I changed the question as I'm still not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can change it by calling `add_data` method of `$wp_scripts` object. This object holds all scripts and information how to render it. To force rendering script in the footer you can do it like this:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse8170_enqueue_scripts' );
function wpse8170_enqueue_scripts() {
    $GLOBALS["wp_scripts"]->add_data( 'jquery', 'group', 1 );
}
```

P.S.: I haven't tested it, but suppose it has to work.

Comment: Just tried this, it caused the following error: Fatal error: Call to a member function add_data() on a non-object

Comment: The latest edit by toscho stops the error coming up but also stops jQuery loading at all.

Comment: @Shaun yes, sorry, forgot to call `global $wp_scripts` before adding data.